# Flutter Toggle List

Tags: flutter, togglebutton

I don't know how to create toggle list like this in flutter.

Here is the image of I'm trying to create :

[Toggle List in Alert Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI2Lj.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RadioListTile()

```
enum Fruit { apple, banana }

Fruit? _fruit = Fruit.apple;

RadioListTile<Fruit>(
  title: const Text('Apple'),
  value: Fruit.apple,
  groupValue: _fruit,
  onChanged: (Fruit? value) {
    setState(() {
      _fruit = value;
    });
  },
)

RadioListTile<Fruit>(
  title: const Text('Banana'),
  value: Fruit.banana,
  groupValue: _fruit,
  onChanged: (Fruit? value) {
    setState(() {
      _fruit = value;
    });
  },
)
```

Comment: Thankx bro. It works like exactly what I want. 